# As of iOS 13, what filetypes does Safari's Download Manager support?

Tags: ios, safari, data-transfer, mobile-safari

As of iOS 13, Safari now includes its own built-in Download Manager; the idea is that for supported filetypes, a user can simply tap on a link from within a web page and Safari will offer to either open the file (essentially mirroring its old behaviour in pre-iOS 13 builds), or download the file to a location of the user's choice which can be changed from within Settings/Safari.

What isn't clear, however, is which filetypes the Download Manager supports. As an example, I've seen a reference to Safari being able to download MP3 files (https://www.cultofmac.com/629362/safari-download-manager-ios-13/), but in my own testing as of iOS 13.2.3, tapping on a link to an MP3 file simply opens it - as was the case in iOS 12.

So, my question - is there a definitive list of filetypes that Safari will offer to download when tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no definitive list of file types which download automatically, since it’s not based on file type but rather the server providing the content. Safari supports **every** file type if the server is set up to provide a download.

You can force a download of a link to a resource rather than opening the link by holding down on the link and choosing Download Linked File.